# Missing Source Files in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm a beginning programmer, so I really don't know too much about IDEs or how they work.  I've been wanting to migrate to the Code::Blocks IDE for a while now.  I wanted to test out a wxWidgets project, but in the process of setting one up, it asked me to select the location of wxWidgets, and said that it must be containing the common "include" and "lib" folders.  I then realized that there weren't either of these folders located in the main "CodeBlocks" program folder.  I've tried reinstalling it (using the "standard" installation option), but to no avail; the issue still stands.  What's weird, however, is that simple console applications that include iostream or stdio.h do work with no errors.  Now, I'm not really *dying* to use wxWidgets, but this brings up the question: ***is this an installation error or a wxWidgets error?***

Comment: Download WxWidgets. See [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/66934-wxwidgets-part-i-getting-set-up/) for more info.

Comment: Seems like installation error as mentioned by @Jesse. Not to malign Code::Blocks but I switched from Eclipse to Code::Blocks for C++ development about a year ago and I've recently gotten sick of it's peculiarities. I just switched to NetBeans which works on the two platforms I'm interested in (Linux, Mac) and find it to be easier to use and more stable. I've also noticed that it looks like Code::Blocks has not been upgraded in some time while the NetBeans community is pretty vibrant and the IDE is still being improved. If you want to start on an IDE, consider NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I'll consider switching to NetBeans for future programming.  Hopefully Code::Blocks doesn't meet the same fate as Dev-C++; it seems to have a lot of potential with all its features.